Expose single classpath resource for web access in Spring Boot
Context:

Spring Boot / Java

Given:

class path resource like /src/main/resources/source_dir/source_file.yaml

Problem:

this file should be exposed on the URL http://localhost:8080/target_dir/target_file.yaml

What is the idiomatic way to achieve it in Spring Boot?
I know there is a way to map a classpath directory to a web path by configuring  ResourceHandlerRegistry but that does not work for a single resource and you can't give the resource another name:
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/target_dir/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/source_dir/");
    }

Currently, I use a trick with forward in the controller so the file can be mapped but that is ugly:
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/target_dir/target_file.yaml")
                .setViewName("forward:/source_dir/source_file.yaml");
    }


I would expect the code like the below to work, but according to the source code of Spring, it can only handle directories:
    // is not working with Spring Boot
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/target_dir/target_file.yaml")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/source_dir/source_file.yaml");
    }


Sure you can specify a single resource. It isn't required to have a pattern. Problem is the resource location which needs to be a directory (afaik). Although you could try to point it to a full path (the code doesn't really prevent this from what I see).

(1) add static (2) example:  /src/main/resources/static/aaa/my-service-spec.yaml , (3) open "http://localhost:8080/aaa/my-service-spec.yaml"

@m-deinum Referencing a single resource with ResourceHandlerRegistry is not supported. It expects a directory.

@life888888 The resource is provided by another library which path is not changeable. And, the question is not about tricks, but about idiomatic Spring Boot way for mapping a single recourse.

@IgorMukhin Is calling ResourceHandlerRegistration#addResourceLocations(Resource...) and implementing custom resource like SingleResource(String path, Sting location) idiomatic enough?

Probably, the simplest solution is to use a controller method which returns a ResponseEntity with the Resource:
@Controller
public class ResourceMappingController {

    @GetMapping("/target_dir/target_file.yaml")
    public ResponseEntity<Resource> get() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(
                new ClassPathResource("/source_dir/source_file.yaml"));
    }
}

Credit: the idea for the solution was suggested by Anghel Ionut but he deleted his answer for an undisclosed reason.

UPDATE
Josh Long showed me that you can just return a Resource from a controller:
@Controller
public class ResourceMappingController {
    private final Resource resource = 
            new ClassPathResource("/source_dir/source_file.yaml")

    @GetMapping("/target_dir/target_file.yaml", produces = "text/yaml")
    @ResponseBody
    public Resource get() {
        return resource;
    }
}


To achieve what you are describing we need this two steps:
1 - To add the directory to the allowed locations
By default Spring Boot configures following directories to be exposed:
classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/
classpath:/META-INF/resources/
classpath:/resources/
classpath:/static/
classpath:/public/

To add another classpath directory (in your case /source_dir/) add this configuration class:
@Configuration
public class MvcConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/source_dir/{filename:source_file.yaml}")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/source_dir/");
    }
}

Please note that the resource handler is for one specific resource only. Other files from the directory won't be exposed.
2 - To configure the renaming of the URL for the file resource
This can be done with the following code added to the above configuration class:
    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/target_dir/target_file.yaml")
                .setViewName("forward:/source_dir/source_file.yaml");
    }


With the above modifications you will get the content of the file /source_dir/source_file.yaml by calling
GET localhost:8080/target_dir/target_file.yaml

Please note: you have already posted a similar code, but for some reason you found it ugly. In my opinion it is not. It uses the exposed and documented callback methods of the WebMvcConfigurer interface only.

I find it not ideal for some reasons: 1) it also exposes the resource unter internal path http://localhost:8080/source_dir/source_file.yaml. This is unwanted behaviour. 2) The configuration is not the easiest to follow.
BTW, it should be "forwand:", not "redirect:", otherwise you are exposing the internal path.

Thanks for the suggestion of the path syntax: "/source_dir/{filename:source_file.yaml}"
I was not aware of that. Do you know where can I find the docs for that?

JavaDoc of addResourceHandler: Patterns such as /static/** or /css/{filename:\\w+\\.css} are supported.

Below is my attempt which exploits ResourceHandlerRegistration#addResourceLocations(Resource...) method:
@Component
public class SingleResourceFactory implements ResourceLoaderAware {

    private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

    @Override
    public void setResourceLoader(ResourceLoader resourceLoader) {
        this.resourceLoader = resourceLoader;
    }

    public Resource singleResource(String path, String location) {
        return (Resource) Proxy.newProxyInstance(
                Resource.class.getClassLoader(),
                new Class<?>[]{Resource.class},
                new SingleResourceInvocationHandler(path, location));
    }

    private class SingleResourceInvocationHandler implements InvocationHandler {

        private final String path;

        private final String location;

        public SingleResourceInvocationHandler(String path, String location) {
            this.path = path;
            this.location = location;
        }

        protected Resource getResource() {
            // todo: do we need to cache result?
            return resourceLoader.getResource(location);
        }

        protected Resource createRelative(Resource proxyObject, String relativePath) throws IOException {
            if (path.equals(relativePath)) {
                return proxyObject;
            }
            return NonExistingResource.INSTANCE;
        }

        @Override
        public Object invoke(Object proxyObject, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
            if (ReflectionUtils.isEqualsMethod(method)) {
                return (proxyObject == args[0]);
            } else if (ReflectionUtils.isHashCodeMethod(method)) {
                return hashCode();
            } else if (ReflectionUtils.isToStringMethod(method)) {
                return "SingleResource proxy: " + path + " -> " + location;
            }

            if ("createRelative".equals(method.getName())) {
                return createRelative((Resource) proxyObject, (String) args[0]);
            }

            return method.invoke(getResource(), args);
        }
    }

    static class NonExistingResource extends AbstractResource {

        static final Resource INSTANCE = new NonExistingResource();

        @Override
        public String getDescription() {
            return "Non existing";
        }

        @Override
        public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
            throw new UnsupportedEncodingException();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean exists() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isReadable() {
            return false;
        }
    }

}

@Autowired
private SingleResourceFactory singleResourceFactory;

@Bean
@Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE - 2)
public WebMvcConfigurer testResourceConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
        @Override
        public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/test/1.txt")
                    .addResourceLocations(singleResourceFactory.singleResource("/test/1.txt", "classpath:/application.properties"));
        }
    };

}



We can add a new SingleUrlHandlerMapping that maps the target path to the constant classpath resource.
@Configuration
class ExampleConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public HandlerMapping handlerMapping() throws Exception {
        var resource = new ClassPathResource("abc/xyz.html");
        var path = "foo/bar.html";

        var requestHandler = new ResourceHttpRequestHandler();
        requestHandler.setResourceResolvers(List.of(new ConstantResourceResolver(resource)));
        requestHandler.afterPropertiesSet();

        var handlerMapping = new SimpleUrlHandlerMapping(Map.of(path, requestHandler));
        handlerMapping.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
        return handlerMapping;
    }

    static class ConstantResourceResolver implements ResourceResolver {
        private final Resource resource;

        public ConstantResourceResolver(Resource resource) {
            this.resource = resource;
        }

        @Override
        public Resource resolveResource(HttpServletRequest request, String requestPath,
                List<? extends Resource> locations, ResourceResolverChain chain) {
            return resource;
        }

        @Override
        public String resolveUrlPath(String resourcePath, List<? extends Resource> locations,
                ResourceResolverChain chain) {
            return resourcePath;
        }
    }

}


An easy way to serve a single resource is to use a RestContolller
Example
@RestController
class SingleYamlResourceController {
    final Resource resource;

    SingleYamlResourceController(@Value("${my.resourse:optional_default_path}") Resource resource) {
        this.resource = resource;
    }

    // produces => "application/yaml" download via browser
    // produces => "text/yaml" human readable in browser
    @GetMapping(value = "target_dir/target_file.yaml", produces = "application/yaml")
    public Resource yaml() {
        return resource;
    }

}

application.properties
my.resourse=classpath:/source_dir/target_file.yaml

This allows you to configure the path to your resource.

What's the point in injecting the resource as @Value and not just creating it with new ClassPathResource?

@IgorMukhin thanks for pointing this out, including application.properties
